# calling my method on onclick of buttoon in view of mvc

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I am new on mvc. 
I have this c# function in my Product controller:

```
public void makebid(int id, decimal price, int userid)
{
    auctionContext db = new auctionContext();
    db.Bids.Add(new Bid() { Auction_ID = id, userID = userid, Price = price });

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

I wanted to call this function from my view on button click with parameters

```
@{
    int value1 = Convert.ToInt32( @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Item1.PA_ID).ToString());
    decimal value2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Request.Form["bidamount"]);
    int value3 = 1;
}

<button type="button" id="makebid" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addbidj()" >Make a Bid</button>
```

Any suggestion how to do call this from view with parameters.

Comment: Whats the point of `int value1 = Convert.ToInt32( @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Item1.PA_ID).ToString());` - it can be just `int value1 = @Model.Item1.PA_ID;`. Use `@Html.ActionLink()` and style it to look like a button if you want the appearance of a button

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try to add such a attribute to your Element : `<button on click="location.href='@Url.Action("Action", "controller")'"></button>`

And using a paramters will look like that

```
<button Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { firstparam = "param", secondparam = "param"})>somebutton</button>`
```